# In libxml2 (C with VS 2015), xmlDoc is not bool, but why does it say bool?

Tags: c, xml-parsing, visual-studio-2015, libxml2, xml-documentation

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

static void print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
        if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            printf("node type: Element, name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
        }
        print_element_names(cur_node->children);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

    if (argc != 2)  return(1);

    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION    // Macro to check API for match with
                           // the DLL we are using

                       /*parse the file and get the DOM */
        if (doc = xmlReadFile("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", NULL, 0) == NULL){
        printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
       }

       /*Get the root element node */
       root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
       print_element_names(root_element);
       xmlFreeDoc(doc);       // free document
       xmlCleanupParser();    // Free globals
       return 0;
   }
```

When I am building it with Visual Studio Pro 2015 (Windows 8, 64 bit), I am getting the following errors:

1. `a value of type "bool" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "xmlDoc *"`
2. `Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'bool' to 'xmlDoc *'`

From the code it suggests that either xmlDoc or xmlReadFile is of type bool, however from the documentation here — http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadFile and http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDoc none of these seem to be of type bool.

I usually code in PHP, this is my first C application, so I am novice.

GTK: I am creating: File > New > Project > VC++ > Empty Project

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? if it's not the data type.

Comment: `doc = xmlReadFile("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", NULL, 0) == NULL` needs `( )` --> `(doc = xmlReadFile("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", NULL, 0)) == NULL`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks!! that solved the issue. I didn't notice it.